# Text positioning for heading. learning flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to put the H2 above the H4.

[image: debug picture]

Comment: Weclome. You need to paste the text of the code here.

Comment: can you please show the code?

Comment: Take a look at [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction). That said, please read our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to add a [mre].

Comment: Hello, and welcome to [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)! You might want to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We also do not post images of the code, instead we paste the code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use display: block;

```
h2, h3 {
 display: block;
}
```

or you can use flex

```
<div class="box">
  <h2>test</h2>
  <h3>test</h3>  
</div>

.box {
  flex-direction: column;
 }
```

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhh. i tried using block but applied it to the container. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this:

```css
.mission {
  /* ... */
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: should i comment out something under mission first?

Comment: No. You just need to add this line.

Comment: it worked! thanks! lol on to the next hurdle

Comment: Great! See ya ;)

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

Flexbox modal is unidirectional. When you define the parent element as `flex`, the direct children follow the main-axis or cross-axis as per the `flex-direction`. Therefore `float`, `clear`, `vertical-align` and `display` properties have no effect on flex items.

### Solution

Add `flex-direction` to `column` as you want the content flow from top-to-bottom

```
.mission {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! hopefully i dont make this mistake much longer lol.